# How do I store the src of an image and compare it to another image in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

The test objective is to confirm that an uploaded images 'src' attribute changes if a user uploads a new image, meaning the image has changed.

I've tried to use a couple approaches, outlined below.

First Approach

```
cy.get('.img').then($img => {
      //store the src

      const source = $('img').attr('src');

      /**
       * File drop 2mb jpg
       */
      cy.fixture(Cypress.env("JPG_2MB_ASSET"), "base64").then(fileContent => {
        cy.get(".dropzone").upload(
          {
            fileContent,
            fileName: "sampleimage.jpg",
            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
          },
          { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
        );
      });
      cy.wait(16000);

      cy.get('img')
        .attr('src')
        .should($src2 => {
          expect($src2).not.to.eq(source);
        });
```

Second Approach

```
      //store the src

      const source = $img.attr('src')

      /**
       * File drop 2mb jpg
       */
      cy.fixture(Cypress.env("JPG_2MB"), "base64").then(fileContent => {
        cy.get(".dropzone").upload(
          {
            fileContent,
            fileName: "sampleimage.jpg",
            mimeType: "image/jpeg"
          },
          { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
        );
      });
      cy.wait(16000);

      cy.get("img").attr('src').should(($src2) => {
        expect($src2).not.to.eq(source)
```

Third Approach

```
    cy.get("img")
      .attr("src")
      .then($src1 => {
        /**
         * File drop 2mb jpg
         */
        cy.fixture(Cypress.env("JPG_2MB"), "base64").then(fileContent => {
          cy.get(".dropzone").upload(
            {
              fileContent,
              fileName: "sampleimage.jpg",
              mimeType: "image/jpeg"
            },
            { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
          );
        });
        cy.wait(16000);

        cy.get('img')
          .attr('src')
          .should($src2 => {
            expect($src2).not.to.eq($src1);
          });
```

The uploads work great, but the comparison of the src does not.

First & Second Approach

Expected- it stores the first image's src as the const `source`, and it drops a 2mb jpg. It then compares the 2nd image's src to the first and confirm they are different.

Result- `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Third Approach

Expected- It stores the first src as `$src1`, and then compares it to the second src, `$src2`

Result- `cy.get(...).attr is not a function`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a plentitude of being angry at my keyboard, I have found the winning solution.

Using `invoke` you can store the value of an attr like `src`, as shown here:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Arguments-are-automatically-forwarded-to-the-function

So, after a few tweaks to the above attempts, I found this to work perfectly:

```
    cy.get('.image-root img').invoke('attr', 'src').then((firstSrc) => {
      const src1 = firstSrc

        /**
         * File drop 2mb jpg
         */
        cy.fixture(Cypress.env("JPG_2MB"), "base64").then(fileContent => {
          cy.get(".dropzone").upload(
            {
              fileContent,
              fileName: "sampleimage.jpg",
              mimeType: "image/jpeg"
            },
            { subjectType: "drag-n-drop" }
          );
        });

        cy.wait(16000);

      cy.get('.image-root img').invoke('attr', 'src').then((nextSrc) => {
        expect(nextSrc).to.not.equal(src1)
      });
    });
```

Comment: Good One J Long