# Compare two objects in cypress which are base64

Tags: javascript, base64, compare, cypress, string-comparison

I'm saving image base64 into variable(base64Image) and would to compare with the image(local) in base64 format but I'm finding error.

```
   var base64Image=res.body.image;
   cy.readFile('cypress/e2e/Testdata/Uber Label.png','base64').then((original) => {
    base64Image.should('eq',original);});
```

I'm expecting it to pass or help me how should I compare both values in cypress

Comment: Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: @Srinidhi Reddy Palwai:  This can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485152/how-do-i-store-the-src-of-an-image-and-compare-it-to-another-image-in-cypress

Comment: var base64Image =
        res.body.completedShipments[0].completedPackages[0].documents[0].image;
      /* cy.readFile("cypress/e2e/Testdata/Uber Label.png", "base64").then(
        (original) => {
          cy.readFile(`cypress/e2e/Testdata/Uber Label.png`, 'base64').should('eq', original)
        }
      ); */
      console.log('from API Test......',base64Image);
      console.log('from Test Code...... ',cy.readFile("cypress/e2e/Testdata/Uber Label.png", "base64"));
      cy.readFile("cypress/e2e/Testdata/Uber Label1.png", "base64").should('eql',base64Image);

Comment: I have re-wrriten my code as above but still there is a difference in base64